# Error using Microsoft SMO libraries to connect to SQL Server database using SQL Login credentials

Tags: sql-server, wcf, smo

I have a database that I am able to access using plain ADO.NET using a connection string that contains a SQL Server Login's username and password. This is done in a WCF service running in IIS.  The machine hosting the SQL Server instance is not the same machine as the one with the web service.

```
connectionString="Data Source=DB_MACHINE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MY_TEST_DB;Connection Timeout=120;User Id=my_web_user;Password=my_pass"
```

I'm writing some methods now that use SMO to see if tables and triggers exist.

I get the following error, which is strange becuase I'm not sure why it matters if the computer name has permission? I'm logging in using the SQL Server Login user name / pass I set up, so why does the error indicate the machine name. The statemetns are being executed by the web servcie which I believe is running under NETWORK SERVICE, but shouldn't it just be using the permissions of the SQL Server Login? And, how do I correct the problem? THe SQL Server Login can access the database when not using SMO.

```
Error generating report: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The server principal "MY_DOMAIN\WEB_SERVICE_COMPUTER$" is not able to access the database "MY_TEST_DB" under the current security context.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   --- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes exe...).
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you mentioned you're using SMO, then you may try:

```
new ServerConnection("servername", "username", "password").ExecuteNonQuery(...)
```

It's good to know that by default WCF service is running under Application Pool dynamic user. Which is 'converting' to NETWORK SERVICE under the network based operations (e.g. connecting to databases) and then NETWORK SERVICE is seen as a machine user account e.g. `mydomain\mypc$`.

If you will not be able to connect as a user specified in connection string, then you can always add mydomain\mypc$ user as a database user and set appropriate privileges.

Keep in mind that SQL Server may not accept proper name of domain, e.g. `mydomain.local.com\mypc$` may not be accepted, try then `mydomain\mypc$`.